# Using json schema within pact for contract testing

Tags: testing, microservices, pact

I started experiencing pact a while a ago, and I'm wondering if any of you guys has any idea if pact support Json schemas!

I'll describe the flow. suppose you have two microservices:

- Microservice A - the consumer
- Microservice B - the Provider

The provider exposes an Api - basically a POST request and expects an explicit json body payload (some field are required).
Let's say:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "Bob"
}
```

both id and name are required properties.

Suppose now that the provider changed it's behaviour to expect the same json payload but with an additional property:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "Bob"
  "extraProperty": "newProperty"
}
```

My question is is there anyway to detect such breaking contract using pact framework? if not what do think is the best way to test such scenario.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is is there anyway to detect such breaking contract using pact framework?

Of course - this is what Pact is designed to do!

If `extraProperty` is a new required field (in addition to `id` and `name`) then when the provider tests run against the contracts generated by the consumer(s) that don't know about the new field, then your API will not behave as they expected and your pact tests will fail.

As to your other question:

> I'm wondering if any of you guys has any idea if pact support Json schemas!

I'm not sure what you mean - we certainly support JSON formats. If you mean [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) then yes, but you still need to write the tests (see https://docs.pact.io/faq#why-doesnt-pact-use-json-schema).